# Using a function to create multiple components and change line automatically [Java]

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout

So i lost some hours already with this and i can't seem to find a solution.

Basically i have a Jframe and inside, i have a Scrollpane and a panel
I have 1 Jlabel, 1 JTextField and 1 JButton inside that panel in a single line.
The JButton can add a new JLabel, a new JTextField and a new JButton, but i can't get them to be positioned in the next line.

I have been messing around with the layouts, but none of them fits my needs, and unfortunaly i never understand or learned how the GUI of java Works.

How's the best way to just keep adding those componentes (Jlabel, Jtextfields and Jbuttons) on a next line for every click i made?

This is my code:

```
private void BtnaddvariableActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
        JLabel Lblvariablextra = new JLabel("Testing");
        PanelVariable.add(Lblvariablextra);
        ScrollPaneVariable.setViewportView(PanelVariable);
}
```

The code only contains an exemple of the label tough.

Comment: "and unfortunaly i never understand or learned how the GUI of java Works." now might be the perfect time

Comment: Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character.

Comment: ControlAltDel, but i don't seem to find a toturial for design either.

Comment: @user3740731 `but i don't seem to find a toturial for design either` What??? I gave you a link to the Swing tutorial which is full of working examples for all Swing components.

Answer (score 1):

Create a main panel that is added to the scroll pane when the GUI is created:

```
Box main = Box.createVerticalBox();
scrollPane.setViewportView( main );
```

Then in the ActionListener you create a child panel contain the 3 components every time the button is pressed:

```
JPanel child = new JPanel();
child.add( new JLabel("I'm a label") );
child.add( new JTextField(10) );
child.add( new JButton("Click Me") );
main.add(child);
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) to understand how layout management works.